# N1 Goi practice question. Synonym of 凌ぐ

Tags: word-choice, words, jlpt

Solving some N1-Goi questions I run up to this one.

> 暑さを「**凌ぐ**」ために、多くの人が都会を離れて山や海で過ごしている。
>
> 1. つのる
> 2. ふせぐ
> 3. いのる
> 4. ふさぐ

I was pretty sure it was the second one 2) ふせぐ" but the solutions provided say its 1)つのる. I don't get it. xD

Can anyone clarify? Maybe I am missing some detail in the nuance of the sentence :P

The link can be found here:
https://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n1-vocabulary-exercise-16/

Comment: None of the four seems very close to 凌ぐ, but if I must choose one, I would choose 2. I don't think this is a good question, so you can ignore this one.

Comment: @naruto and OP, why would you think it's ふせぐ? I understand that verb to mean "to block; to prevent". In the context of the sample sentence, I understand 凌【しの】ぐ to mean "to bear; to get through a difficulty". The "get through" sense is almost the opposite of "to block"; besides which, one doesn't prevent the heat of summer by going to the mountains or the beach, one just avoids it.  For that matter, none of these seem fitting options -- I'd expect たえる or こらえる as synonyms, maybe 避【さ】ける or 逃【に】げる (not synonyms, but still fitting the context). Any chance the answer key is wrong?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Looking at the link, it says *closest in meaning*, so it may be that the intention of the problem is not necessarily synonyms. Or it may be simply a bad question.

Comment: indeed, we are not looking for an exact synonym, but a word that could possibly fit in the place of 凌ぐ... Chances are this is simply a bad question though.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I wouldn't say 防ぐ and 凌ぐ are similar, but they do share a common point of "dealing with undesirable things". On the other hand, 暑さを募る/塞ぐ make almost no sense regardless of the context.

Comment: @naruto, thank you for the sanity check!  I was curious if there were some sense to these words that I didn't know, that might have made them more appropriate to this context. Sounds like they don't, and something just went funny with how this question was drafted. I'll see if there's any way of providing feedback to that website's maintainers. Cheers!